# How to Union List<List<String>> in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm having a `List<List<String>>`, and which contains

```
{  {"A" , "B" }, 
   {"C" , "D" }
}
```

I need to union all the innerlist into another list

So the resulting `List<String>` will contain

```
     {"A","B","C","D"}
```

Now im using `for loop` to do this

Is there any way to do this Using `LINQ` or `Lambda Expression`.

Please help me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if there are duplicates in your lists?

Comment: Performing union operation in list will discard the duplicates

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not Exactly a Union, but you can try this

```
YourList.SelectMany(l=>l).Distinct()
```

Comment: Actually, Union is really just Concat().Distinct().  Instead of Concat, you use SelectMany since it is a list of lists... So... in other words... this is the only correct answer I see here.  All other answers neglect that there may be duplicates.  The OP wants Union which gets rid of dupes.

Comment: Does .NET provide the identity function somewhere in the BCL? Both Haskell and Scala have it (and in Ruby, I always add it myself), and it makes code like this easier to read, IMHO. In Ruby, the above would roughly be `your_list.flat_map {|l| l }.uniq`, but with the following definition `IDENTITY = -> x { x }` it could be written as `your_list.flat_map(&IDENTITY)`. In Scala, it would be `yourList flatMap identity` and in Haskell `yourList >>= id`, which is much easier to read than `yourList flatMap(e => e)` or `yourList >>= \x -> x`. Is there `YourList.SelectMany(Identity)`?

Answer (score 14):

```
List<List<string>> collections = new List<List<string>>()
        {
          new List<string>(){"A" , "B" }, 
          new List<string>() {"C" , "D" }
        };

var list = collections.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

SelectMany builds up a expression tree that when evaluated flattens the list of list to a single list of combined members.

ToList forces the expression tree to be evaluated and which results in a List.

If you want to eliminate duplicates you can add a Distinct call before the call to 'ToList()'

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) extension method.

```
List<List<String>> masterList = { {"A" , "B" }, {"C" , "D" } };

IEnumerable<string> results = masterList.SelectMany(l => l);
```

Comment: Does not result in a List<string>.

Comment: Can only use array initializer expressions to assign to array types. Try using a new expression instead.

Comment: This answer does not account for duplicates.  Not a union of lists.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = myLists.SelectMany(l => l);
```

Comment: This answer does not account for duplicates.  Not a union of lists.

Comment: @Brian: The OP added the duplicates requirement after this answer was posted.

Comment: The OP asked how to union all of the lists.  The union operator, by definition, excludes duplicates.  This is true both in set theory and in the Union implementation in LINQ.  Your solution does not give the union of the sets.  It gives the sets concatenated together.  It is different.

Answer (score 3):

How about Aggregate?

```
myLists.Aggregate((left, right) => left.Union(right));
```

To me, this is more expressive than using SelectMany, because it is telling you exactly what you are doing:  **Aggregate your list of lists by calling union on them all.**

Comment: +1 ... I agree with you ... It's more expressive than SelectMany

Answer (score 1):

Just for kicks:

```
(from list in theList from e in list select e).Distinct().ToList()
```

This is of course the same solution as @Alexander Taran's, just with query syntax instead of lambda syntax. (Or at least it should be – I don't have my LINQPad handy.)