# what's the best way to return a List from a list of Lists of a base class based on string passed in

Tags: c#, find, ilist

what's the best way to return a List from a list of Lists of a base class based on string passed in.  I've got:

```
public List<myBaseData> FindFromListofLists(string aClass, List<List<myBaseData>> data)
{
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        foreach(myBaseData baseData in item)
        {
            if (baseData.ToString().CompareTo(aClass) == 0) //not sure if this is the best way as if the class overides the toString method...
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;


}
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) candidate. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
public List<myBaseData> FindFromListofLists(
      string aClass, List<List<myBaseData>> data)
{

  return data.Find(
      item => item
              .Where(d => d.ToString().CompareTo(aClass) == 0)
              .Count() > 0);

}
```

You can also try to write it as -

```
return data.Find(item => item.Select(x => x.ToString()).Contains(aClass));
```

*Please note that the code is untested :P*

Comment: +1 - tried with simple List&lt;List&lt;string&gt;&gt; - it looks like second example 3 times faster then first one, and slightly faster then foreach/foreach and for/for cycle

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

[How to Union List<List<String>> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515876/how-to-union-listliststring-in-c)

And then you can use the `.Where()` method to narrow down the results to those matching `aClass`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
            if (((List<myBaseData>)item).Contains(aClass)) ;
            {
                return (item);
            }
```

instead of your second "foreach".
and that's the great thing about dynamic lists.

Comment: not sure this will work as aClass is a string that is the name of the object that the IList should contain.  However, this might work: if (((List<myBaseData>)item).Contains(Type.GetType(aClass)))

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Dictionary<string, List<myBaseData>>` or `Dictionary<Type, List<myBaseData>>` insted of `List<List<myBaseData>>`

The Dictionary-s `TryGet` method does exactly what you need in `FindFromListofLists`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is this.

```
public class MyBaseClass{}
public class MyChildClass : MyBaseClass{}
```

then somewhere else you want to return only the MyChildClass objects.
this is what you need to do:

```
public IEnumerable<MyBaseClass> GetFilteredObjects(Type type, List<List<MyBaseClass>> lists)
{
  foreach(var list in lists)
  {
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
      if(item.GetType() == type)
        yield return item;
    }
  }
}
```

then you call this method like this:

```
var myChildClasses = GetFilteredObjects(typeof(MyChildClass), listOfLists);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.